# Loading pages dynamically in SplitView in jQuery mobile

Tags: jquery-mobile, dynamic-data, ipad

I am a newbee on this jquery mobile platform.

I have a splitview in my application... As in left page(which is 20%) and right page(which is 80%).

I have states coming from the database in the left panel and when one of the state is clicked... their corresponding information in the right panel....(the information too is coming from the database).

Now the problem is... when I click on any state for the first time.. its information gets displayed on the right panel...
But when I click any state for the second time... the previous state information only stays.. the right panel is not getting refreshed as and when I click on the other states...

Thanks in advance....

```js
$('#main').live('pageshow', function(event, ui) {
    console.log("States show");
    onDeviceReadyStates();

});
    $('#content').live('pageshow', function(event, ui) {
    console.log("Content show");
    onDeviceReadyContent(sid);
    console.log("contentsid: " + sid);
});
```

Made use of the router plugin....to pass the parameters....

Comment: empty the div before loading again!

Comment: What method are you using to load the state info? Show us some code so we can tell what your doing.

Comment: do you specify a target panel for where the information should go?

Comment: @frequent: yeah I have provided the target panel....